# Access violation in Visual Studio when compiled with Multi-threaded Debug DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, segmentation-fault, gdal, ogr

I am building an application using the *GDAL/OGR* library and have faced a really strange issue, namely getting an *access violation* error when running my program compiled with **Multi-threaded Debug DLL** (`/MDd`) *runtime library* option. The following example is a minimal sample to demonstrate the problem:

```
#include <ogr_geometry.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    OGRPoint *point = new OGRPoint;
    delete point; // segmentation fault
    return 0;
}
```

Similar problem occurs with other OGR types in the *GDAL/OGR* library, so it is not related to the `OGRPoint` class. However there is no issue when the memory is allocated on the stack and not on the heap.

The code executes fine when I use the *Multi-threaded DLL* configuration instead. (So basically Release mode is good, but Debug mode runs into the mentioned access violation error.) The program also runs fine on Linux compiled with `g++`.

The callstack is the following:

```
ntdll.dll!_RtlReportCriticalFailure@8() Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlpHeapHandleError@4()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlpLogHeapFailure@24()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlFreeHeap() Unknown
AcLayers.dll!6d7158bf() Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for AcLayers.dll]  
gdal201.dll!0f87bdbd()  Unknown
TestProject.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 7    C++
[External Code]
```

Any ideas on what is causing this problem?

Comment: Your conclusion, that everything is ok with the release version of the CRT is likely wrong. It merely exhibits different behavior due to a bug. Probably an uninitialized pointer that is zero-initialized in a release build, but gets a specific pattern (0xcdcdcdcd) in a debug build.

Comment: I also thought about that @IInspectable, therefore I checked the source code, since it is an open source library. Although the `OGRPoint` class has a member pointer, it is properly initialized to `NULL` in the constructor and checked before deletion in the destructor.

Comment: Also, if the issue would be what you mentioned, a segfault should also arise when the object in created on the stack. However it works fine in that case.

Comment: Not familiar with the `GDAL/OGR library` but is it using the (same) CRT itself, and are there different LIBs to link in debug vs. release configs?

Comment: @dxiv: the build script of the `GDAL/OGR` library does not produce different libs for debug/release configs. Previously I only worked with the `GDAL` part of the library, where I did not encountered this heap corruption issue. However I started searching now based on your comment and it looks like you have a good point. Although unfortunately it seems like they are not intending to deal with this issue: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3346